# Priority among transactions with same fees

Tags: blockchain, transaction-fees, txpool

If there are too many transactions in the mempool to be included in a single block, and assuming they all have the same transaction fee per kB, will the older transactions be mined first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, the primary sorting criterion is fee/byte. The secondary sorting priority is transaction age in the monerod source. Of course, any code creating a block is free to make its own selection/priority choices, so this only applies to monerod.

Answer (score 2):

It's up to the miner which transactions will be chosen to be included in a block, so a miner might optimise his selection to fill as much as possible of the available block size limit.

Comment: Do you know what the default algorithm does?